# Itext7 HTML2PDF - Picture not rotated in PDF file

Tags: powershell, itext7

I have an HTML file with some rotated pictures. When I convert the HTML file to a PDF file the picture is not rotated. It seems that EXIF &0112 is not applied correctly.

```
[iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($HTMLInputFile,$PDFFileToWrite)
```

[image]

Left the input HTML file, right the created PDF file.

My question is how to make sure that the picture has the correct orientation in the created PDF file.

Feedback is appreciated and with kind regards,
Willem-Jan

Comment: Can you attach the sample file to reproduce the problem?

Comment: [Link to ZIP file with the pictures, HTML file and PDF file](https://www.vroom.cc/PictureDetailsWithForms_v02.zip)

Answer (score 1):

pdfHTML indeed does not support rotation flag in EXIF data at the moment (pull requests are [welcome](https://github.com/itext/i7n-pdfhtml)).

As a workaround, you can customize your tag worker factory to plugin in your own implementation for handling `<img>` tags. There you can plug in your own implementation to perform image rotation. What I will be doing is reading the rotation flag from EXIF using [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library and applying additional property, namely, `Image#setRotationAngle()`. Another option could be just reading the image and the rotation flag, and rotating the image and replacing the image contents in place (so that we replace the original image with its exact copy except that no rotation flags are used, i.e. image is rotated if needed before removing the flag), e.g. by placing the Base64-encoded value into the `src` attribute.

Here we create a custom tag worker factory:

```
private static class CustomTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if ("img".equals(tag.name())) {
            return new RotationAwareImgTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
}
```

And here comes the meaty part - parsing the image and applying our properties in a custom tag worker:

```
private static class RotationAwareImgTagWorker extends ImgTagWorker {
    private int rotation = 0;

    public RotationAwareImgTagWorker(IElementNode element,
            ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void processEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super.processEnd(element, context);
        String src = element.getAttribute(AttributeConstants.SRC);
        PdfXObject imageXObject = context.getResourceResolver().retrieveImageExtended(src);
        if (imageXObject instanceof PdfImageXObject && ((PdfImageXObject) imageXObject).identifyImageType() == ImageType.JPEG) {
            Metadata metadata = null;
            try {
                metadata = ImageMetadataReader
                        .readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(((PdfImageXObject) imageXObject).getImageBytes()));
                ExifIFD0Directory directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
                if (directory.containsTag(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_ORIENTATION)) {
                    int orientation = directory.getInt(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_ORIENTATION);
                    if (orientation != 0) {
                        switch (orientation) {
                            case 1:
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                this.rotation = 270;
                                break;
                            default:
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // TODO
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // TODO
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        IPropertyContainer baseResult = super.getElementResult();
        if (baseResult instanceof Image) {
            ((Image) baseResult).setRotationAngle(Math.PI * rotation / 180);
        }
        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

To put it all together, we need to utilize `ConverterProperties`:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setTagWorkerFactory(new CustomTagWorkerFactory());
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(sourceHtml), new File(outPdf), properties);
```

And here comes the visual result:

[image: result]

If you want to use PowerShell then probably you should build your own small custom library around iText and call that library instead of implementing the above option in PowerShell. Note that the answer is written in Java but porting to .NET should be a trivial matter of capitalizing some letter names etc, and `metadata-extractor` library is available both on Java and .NET, similarly to iText.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Alexey. I already have a PS function that returns the orientation value. Assume the orientation value is 6, the corresponding value is 270. So the SetRotationAngle = 3.14 * 270 / 180 = 4,71. Is that a good summary or do I miss certain items? Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: No, that's true, for orientation value `6` the rotation is indeed `PI * 270 / 180`

Comment: Tomorrow, I will give it a try. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Alexey, do I have to make this adjustment for each picture or globally at the end while the PDF is created?

Comment: The code that I attached affects each JPEG picture with specified orientation

Comment: `$ConverterProperties = [iText.Html2pdf.ConverterProperties]::new()
$ConverterProperties.`

The most difficult part is to translate the Java stuff to PowerShell. My frieds Google and Bing are not of big help. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve this issue. The solution is to make a base64 image, and rotate that base64 image if needed. Then that base64 image can be used in the HTML file. As the base64 does not contain any rotation information itext7 can handle this quite well.

The code:

```
  Function Make-Base64Image
   {

    <#
    .NOTES
    =============================================================================================================================================
    Created with:     Windows PowerShell ISE
    Created on:       28-Oct-2022, modified on 11-Nov-2022
    Created by:       TheStingPilot
    Organization:     
    Functionname:     Make-Base64Image
    =============================================================================================================================================
    .SYNOPSIS

    This function converts and rotates a picture and convert it to a base64 image. 
    Only than Itext7 HTMLToPDF can handle the orientation. 

    #>

    Param
     (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [System.IO.FileInfo] $SourceFileName,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][Int]                $Scale = 100,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] [Int]                $Orientation
     )
   

    $img          = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($SourceFileName)
    $ImgFormat    = [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg
        
    $Size         = "$([int]($img.Width*($Scale/100))), $([int]($img.Height*($Scale/100)))"
    $img_new      = New-Object -TypeName System.Drawing.Bitmap($img, $Size)
    $MemoryStream = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.MemoryStream

    If ($Orientation -eq 2) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::RotateNoneFlipX) }
    If ($Orientation -eq 3) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::RotateNoneFlipXY)}
    If ($Orientation -eq 4) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::RotateNoneFlipY) }
    If ($Orientation -eq 5) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate90FlipX)   }
    If ($Orientation -eq 6) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate90FlipNone)}
    If ($Orientation -eq 7) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate90FlipY)   }
    If ($Orientation -eq 8) {$img_new.RotateFlip([System.Drawing.RotateFlipType]::Rotate90FlipXY)  }

    $img_new.Save($MemoryStream, $ImgFormat)
    $cImgBytes    = [Byte[]]($MemoryStream.ToArray())
    $sBase64      = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($cImgBytes)

    $img_new.Dispose()

    Return $sBase64
       
   }
```

The correct img tag will be:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,--code--</img>
```

You can also use the rotation flag in the img tag, like <style="transform:         rotate(90deg);"

But in that case, you need to have a box with the same width and height. You can handle the object position with object-postion but itext7 cannot take that.

That is why I would like to advise you to use the base64 image and rotate that if needed.

Cheers!