# How to find coordinates of any PDF object

Tags: c#, itext7

I am generating PDF files from HTML ones using wkhtmltopdf. I would like to get the coordinates and size of an object in the PDF. For example, supose I add an image object in the HTML file with a tag like this: `<img id="myimg" src="image.png" with="100" height="100"/>`. I wonder whether is it possible to get the image's position and size in the generated PDF. Please, take into account that the object does not have to be an image. Whichever object mapped from the HTML file to the final PDF would do the trick.

I am using itext7 (v7.2.1, .NET version) to analyse the PDF file. So far, I have been able to read the PDF objects in the document, but I have not been successful in getting their identifiers. I would need to identify each object to filter the one I am looking for and get its coordinates afterwards.

```
private static async Task<int> AnalyzeFileAsync(string filePath)
{
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument( new PdfReader(filePath) );
            //IEventListener listener = new 
            //PdfCanvasProcessor proc = new PdfCanvasProcessor();
            int objNum = doc.GetNumberOfPdfObjects();
            for ( int i = 1; i < objNum; i++ )
            {
                PdfObject obj = doc.GetPdfObject(i);
            }
}
```

I created this test PDF file with just one image inside it: [blank.pdf](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/SRIhTN9X#link). The original HTML text is this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img id="aaaaaaaaaaaaa" src="p.png" with="100" height="100"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I believed that the `aaaaaaaaaaaaa` identifier would be mapped into the PDF, but it seems that is not the case. Hence, I do not know how to insert and get a specific object in the PDF.

Could you please give me a hand with this?

Regards,

Comment: (just a quick comment while I look at your PDF file, but according to the producer line, you used iText 7.1.10 to open it, and not 7.2.1)

Comment: I'm not familiar with wkhtmltopdf, but maybe you can create a tagged PDF out of the original HTML that will help you navigate through the structure of your document, potentially with some _alt_ magic for identifiers? with pdfHTML, you can always use some [custom tag workers](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers) as seen on this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67962719/1566339).

Comment: you can also get coordinates/object as they are being rendered as seen on this [knowledge base article](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-get-the-co-ordinates-of-an-image) specific to getting images.

Comment: Do you need the position of _all_ objects? Or of _just one specific_ object you are even free to predefine the type of? The former case is difficult as for a number of html objects you don't get a single object each but instead multiple objects. E.g. a span with underlined text will become a text object (or a part of one or multiple ones) and a line (or a thin and long rectangle). Bitmap images are easier to determine the position of, see @André's links. The best option would be a HTML form element *if your html converter transforms it into a PDF AcroForm form field*.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. I need just the coordinates of one specific object, and I am also free to predefine its type. Nevertheless, I can not use HTML Forms as I need a plain text PDF, not one with form elements like textboxes and so on. I will take a look at @AndréLemos' links and get back to you.

Comment: you can always flatten the form to make it a "plain text PDF" if that's a concern

Comment: So far, I have been able to get image information with a class that implements the interface IEventListener. However, the image's identifier is not present in the PDF file. I though I could identify the image calculating the hash of the stream. Nevertheless, PNG files are modified while generating the PDF. On the other hand, it seems that JPG images are placed verbatim into the PDF. I will try the AcroForm way.

Comment: @JesúsÁngel, that's because the PDF format does not support all image types, so conversions need to be made (it does support JPEG for instance, that's why you get that behaviour)

Comment: For easier recognition of elements you should consider switching to a html-to-pdf converter that supports proper tagging. Who knows, maybe wkhtmltopdf merely requires some configuration setting for that, too...